# Formulário com o CSS

Tags: css, mobile

Eu desenvolvi uma aplicação mobile e não estou conseguindo manter o layout responsivo em outros aparelhos...

Vocês podem me dar um exemplo de um CSS e um formulário com o CSS aplicado?

Qualquer ajuda, eu agradeço muito! :D

Comment: Florence primeiramente bem vinda. Segundamente clique no link de edição logo no final da sua pergunta e inclua o código do seu formulário, tanto HTML quanto CSS. Só assim podemos te dar uma resposta precisa. Sem essas informações sua pergunta será fecha por não ser clara o suficiente, ou não ter um exemplo mínimo viável para simularmos o problema

Comment: No https://codepen.io/ geralmente se encontra muitos exemplos de codigo em html e css

Comment: Florence, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Florence. Para criar formulários responsivos você pode utilizar uma propriedade chamada media query. Que segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) da *MDN* é:

> Consiste de um media type e pelo menos uma expressão
>   que limita o escopo das folhas de estilo usando media features, tal
>   como largura, altura e cor. Media queries, adicionadas no CSS3, deixam
>   a apresentação do conteúdo adaptado a uma gama especifica de
>   dispositivos não precisando mudar o conteúdo em si.

Portanto, a media query pode ser usada para alterar a propriedade visual de um elemente sob determinada circunstância.

Veja esse exemplo para um formulário:

```css
.central {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.form-group {
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .form-group {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.btn {
  background-color: #C8D6E5;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="central">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" class="field">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email" class="field">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Telefone:</label>
      <input type="text" class="field">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subject">Assunto:</label>
      <input type="text" class="field">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Mensagem:</label>
      <textarea cols="10" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>
```

Nele nós temos uma `div` chamada `form-group`. Essa `div` tem 3 propriedades CSS. Dentre elas uma que regula o seu tamanho em 50% da `div` "mãe". Logo, ela não ocupará todo o formulário.

Só que se você diminuir a página até uma certa largura verá que não ficará responsiva, ou melhor, não visualmente agradável. Conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que a `div` está só com 50% de uma largura bem pequena.

Para resolver isso usamos a media query, que segundo o exemplo apresentado anteriormente irá definir que na largura de 700px, ou melhor, quando a tela chegar em 700px a `div` `form-group` irá ocupar os 100% da tela, resolvendo o problema.

Isso é só um pequeno exemplo de media query. Elas podem ser usadas para diferentes tipos de problemas e situações.